# Encrypted swap partition does not show up in /dev/mapper

Tags: encryption, swap, cryptsetup

I followed these steps to convert my normal swap on `/dev/sda4` (UUID `5da9c956-e544-47e3-bb8e-fe18d9531b2f`) into an encrypted swap partition on 16.04:

- Disable old swap partition and overwrite it with zeroes:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda4 bs=4M
  ```
- Install `cryptsetup`:

  ```
  sudo apt install cryptsetup
  ```
- Edit `/etc/crypttab` to contain this:

  ```
  # <target name> <source device>                 <key file>  <options>
  cryptswap   UUID=5da9c956-e544-47e3-bb8e-fe18d9531b2f   /dev/urandom    swap
  ```
- Edit `/etc/fstab` to remove the old swap line and replace it with this one:

  ```
  # cryptswap on /dev/sda4 configured in /etc/crypttab
  /dev/mapper/cryptswap               none        swap    sw  0   0
  ```
- Reload cryptdisks configuration:

  ```
  sudo service cryptdisks reload
  sudo service cryptdisks-early reload
  ```
- Enable the new encrypted swap:

  ```
  sudo swapon -a
  ```

However, this last step gave me the following error message:

```
swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap failed: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, the encrypted device file seems not to have been created:

```
$ ls -la /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      60 Aug 10 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    4780 Aug 10 20:16 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Aug 10 18:50 control
```

What went wrong here and how do I get my encrypted swap partition to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem with your `/etc/crypttab` file that's causing eveything to go south, and a problem with your swap partition.

First off, you need to `mkswap` the partition that you want to use for your encrypted swap file. The cryptdisk utility expects your partition to be swap, so you should keep it as such:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sda4
```

Now, note that this will change the partition's UUID. Get the new one with the following command, and make note of it:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda4
```

Now, we need to deal with the larger problem at hand: your `/etc/crypttab` file. Replace it with the following:

```
# <target name>  <source device>        <key file>     <options>
cryptswap        UUID=<Your new UUID>   /dev/urandom   swap,offset=1024
```

Reboot the system, and you should have a working swap!

---

You have your `cryptswap` set up currently to recreate the entire partition as an encrypted swap. This is Not Good™, because we need to preserve the UUID. By offsetting the swap by 1024 blocks, we preserve the critical filesystem info, including the UUID.

Comment: Good answer, your answer solved [my problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187686/180452)

Comment: Great tip of the offsetting!